# Comparing 2 columns in Pandas DataFrame and populating a 3rd column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that has 2 int columns inside, 'CNT' and 'STG_TABLE_CNT'.  I want to add a new column 'IS_MATCH' that returns 'Y' if 'CNT' and 'STG_TABLE_CNT' have the same value, or 'N' if they do not.

I tried this:

```
if result['CNT'] == result['STG_TABLE_CNT']:
    result['IS_MATCH'] = 'Y'
else:
    result['IS_MATCH'] = 'N'
```

but that is throwing the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I realize it is searching for equality (True/False) I am just not sure how to get around that to return 'Y' or 'N' instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), it's faster than `apply` or `itterating`:

```
import numpy as np

df['IS_MATCH'] = np.where(result['CNT'].eq(result['STG_TABLE_CNT']), 'Y', 'N')
```

Answer (score 1):

`result['CNT'] == result['STG_TABLE_CNT']` gives you a whole series, and `pandas` is complaining that it does not know how to convert that series into `True` or `False`. What you really want is something like

```
result['IS_MATCH'] = (result['CNT'] == result['STG_TABLE_CNT']).\
                         apply(lambda x: 'Y' if x else 'N')
```

or

```
result['IS_MATCH'] = (result['CNT'] == result['STG_TABLE_CNT']).\
                         map({True: 'Y', False: 'N'})
```

Comment: thank you, your explaining as to why the error was happening was useful as well